# MDB subscribing to remote jms topic in Apache Tomee

Tags: jms, apache-tomee

I'm trying out Apache Tomee (1.5 plus) for the first time and I'm totally stuck at the moment.

The company I work for have an application (using JBoss and HornetQ) that sends messages to a JMS topic, topic/theTopicsName.

I'm trying to implement another service using Tomee/ActiveMQ that subscribes to said topic, usually from another computer to handle the messages in an MDB, but I can't get it to listen other than to localhost.

If I've understood correctly it should be possible to add something like

```xml
<Resource id="MyJmsResourceAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
    BrokerXmlConfig =
    ServerUrl       =  tcp://thehostname:5455
</Resource>

<Resource id="MyJmsConnectionFactory" type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory">
    ResourceAdapter = MyJmsResourceAdapter
</Resource>
```

In my /conf/tomee.xml

Question is how do I go about make my MDB use the settings above? Is it possible through annotations or ejb-jar.xml?

Say I have a simple MDB

```java
public class MessageListenerMDB implements MessageListener {

    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

    public MessageListenerMDB() {}

    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        //print message
    }
}
```

And my */WEB_INF/ejb-jar.xml looks like

```xml
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" metadata-complete="true">
  <enterprise-beans>
    <message-driven>
      <ejb-name>MessageListenerMDB</ejb-name>
      <ejb-class>my.package.jms.MessageListenerMDB</ejb-class>
      <messaging-type>javax.jms.MessageListener</messaging-type>
      <activation-config>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>
            destinationType
          </activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>
            javax.jms.Topic
          </activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
        <activation-config-property>
          <activation-config-property-name>
            destination
          </activation-config-property-name>
          <activation-config-property-value>
            /topic/theTopicsName
          </activation-config-property-value>
        </activation-config-property>
      </activation-config>

      <resource-ref>
        <res-ref-name>
          java:comp/env/my.package.jms.MessageListenerMDB/connectionFactory
        </res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.jms.ConnectionFactory</res-type>
        <injection-target>
          <injection-target-class>
            my.package.jms.MessageListenerMDB
          </injection-target-class>
        <injection-target-name>connectionFactory</injection-target-name>
      </injection-target>
    </resource-ref>

    </message-driven>
  </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

What do I have to do to make it use the ConnectionFactory above?
Am I totally wrong from the beginning?

Friendly regards /Magnus

Comment: The above should work just fine.  There isn't much detail on what is going wrong.  How are you determining messages are going to localhost?  The server log output would be helpful.